# jQuery ui autocomplete no search results

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-autocomplete

I am getting no search results from my mysql database using php. I've tried using mysqli, and PDO style from [here](http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/).

**html**

```
<div id="tags_wrapper">
    <p>Tags</p>
    <input type="text" class="txtTag" placeholder="Start entering tag..">      </input>
</div>
```

**jQuery**: located in php page at root/Blog/panel.php, 'source' located in root/Blog/_class/tag_filler.php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.txtTag').autocomplete(
        {
            source:'/_class/tag_filler.php',
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
</script>
```

**php source [mysqli]**: Brisktilities.php creates an instance of mysqli that I use below.

```
include_once 'BriskUtilities.php';

$util = new BriskUtilities();
$mysqli = $util->getMysqli();
if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $search = $_GET['term'];
    if($queryTags = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Tag_T WHERE tValue LIKE %".$search."% ORDER BY tValue ASC")) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryTags)) {
            $results[] = array('id' => $row['tID'], 'label' => $row['tValue']);
        }
        echo json_encode($results);
    }
$mysqli->close();
}
```

**php source [PDO]**: Still no search results with PDO. My DB is **brisk**, my table is **tag_t**, and my connection is working properly. Any suggestions?

```
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("<p class='error'>Sorry, we were unable to connect to the database server.</p>");
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$return_arr = array();

if ($conn)
{
    $ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tag_t where tValue like :term";
    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
    $result->execute();

    /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
        $row_array['value'] = $row['tValue'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
}
$conn = null; 
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

**Update**
GET 'term' not found (error goes away when changing source to Blog/_class/tag_filler.php, but still no search results returned. I am using the database on the same page and it's fetching results for another table fine):

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) [http] site.local/_class/tag_filler.php?term=an
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) site.local/_class/tag_filler.php?term=and
GET site.local/_class/tag_filler.php?term=my 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.1.js:8526
```

Comment: I recently was working on a search engine with JQuery and auto complete. It to used MySQLi. The place I went for a great tutorial ishttp://youhack.me/2010/04/28/creating-a-fancy-search-feature-with-php-mysql-and-jquery/ the download works right out of the box, and I simply replaced the dabase with mine and did some minor changes to the code. But it works great and it is auto complete.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you fix the engine from mysql injections.

Comment: Can you re-phrase that

Comment: The search engine in the tutorial works great as intended. But it is for educational purposes. It has vulnerabilities call MySQL injections that can be exploited. You would need to fix them if your serious about your site

Comment: oh okay yeah I understand how to prevent injections

Answer (score 0):

When using like you need to enclose the value within quotes. e.g. `tValue like '%my_value%'`.

Note the use of single quotes in the following (I'm only showing the lines that need to be updated):

In your **mysqli**:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Tag_T WHERE tValue LIKE '%".$search."%' ORDER BY tValue ASC")
```

and in your **PDO**:

```
$ac_term = "'%".$_GET['term']."%'";
```

**Update:**

If you've already tried this then please add some error handling so that you can narrow down the source of the problem.

For **mysqli** (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php):

```
$queryTags = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Tag_T WHERE tValue LIKE %".$search."% ORDER BY tValue ASC");
if (!$queryTags) {
    printf("Error: %s", mysqli_error($mysqli));
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryTags)) {
    $results[] = array('id' => $row['tID'], 'label' => $row['tValue']);
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

For **PDO** (
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php):

```
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Comment: @user2690805, suggest adding some error handling on your mysqli and pdo implementation to debug the problem.  Please see respective links from the update.

Comment: update: I noticed in the console that I am getting a 404 on the GET for 'term'

Comment: Is `_check/tag_filter.php` in your document root?

Comment: no, it goes: site > Blog > _class > tag_filler.php, and the php page referencing it is in Blog

Comment: Assuming site is your document root, in your query update this line `source:'/Blog/_class/tag_filler.php'`

Comment: So that gets rid of the 404 error, but still no search results are returned. I have valid values in the table. I even tried moving tag_filler.php to the same directory